# React Native Router Flux only spins/never loads

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

So in getting here I found that I was unable to use the property renderLeftButton for react-native-router-flux. The error it gave me was of no use and returned 15 different solutions, none of which were relevant for me. I found in the changelog something that may have indicated I needed a newer version, 4.0.2. I was on 4.0.0-beta.31 previously I think. So for the last 6 hours I have been trying to do that but have not succeeded and I can't even find anyone else having this problem.

When I start the app it's supposed to go the initial scene page, this has been working for months and no changes have been made to the code, just the version change. Instead of working, or showing me a useless error message it just shows a spinning loading indicator. No error messages in the console from remote debug, nothing in the node server, no google results for searching up my problem.

These are my current versions:

```
  "react": "16.4.1",
  "react-native": "0.57.1",
  "react-native-router-flux": "4.0.2", //I also tried ^4.0.0 which goes up to 4.0.6 which had the same problem
```

I tried it initially with "react-native": "0.56.0", but changes to 57.1 based on one of the answers I found, but nothing changed when I did that.

I can either keep trying to fix this, and the next waves of version errors that will come after it, or I can go to the backup of the project and start at square one trying to fix a problem based on a completely generic error message. I think I've read that renderLeftButton was introduced with 4.0.0 so it SHOULD be available to me in 4.0.0-beta.31 if that's accurate.

I think pursuing the upgrade is the right choice but I am certain of nothing, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
const MainRouter = () => {
return (
    <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
            <Scene type="reset" key="login">
                <Scene hideNavBar key="loginForm" component={LoginForm} title="Login" initial />
            </Scene>
            <Drawer
                type="reset"
                hideNavBar
                key="drawer"
                contentComponent={DrawerContent}
                drawerImage={MenuIcon}
                drawerWidth={300}
                drawerPosition={'right'}
                tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({ main: { opacity: (2 - ratio) / 2 } })}
            >   
                <Scene key="demo" component={demo} title="demo" renderLeftButton={() => <Text>Left</Text>} />
```

^Scene config

Comment: Would it be possible to share your Scene config?

Comment: @kenmistry OK, is that what you meant by scene config?

Comment: yes, that's right. i am not seeing anything out of the ordinary. can you try this? replace `type="reset"` with `type={ActionConst.RESET}`, and do remember to import `ActionConst` from rnrf.

Comment: @kenmistry No difference I'm afraid. I changed out both the one in <drawer> and <scene>.

Comment: @kenmistry I deleted the cache/data for the app and rebuilt it and was able to properly load the router. but only once. Launching the app a second+ time has it spinning endlessly again. I imagine that's a big hint about what's going on but I don't know what it indicates.

Comment: it is very peculiar that it only works the first time round. just wondering, how do you go about "launching the app the 2nd time"? do you use live reload or hot reloading while making changes to the scene config? because on my end, hot reloading doesn't help while making changes to my scene config, a reload does.

Comment: @kenmistry I run react-native run-android from CMD again to relaunch. I think I got burned once or twice with the live reload and it not grabbing the most recent change I had made so I tend to avoid it.

Comment: that's strange. not sure if we are on the same page. whenever there is a change, live reload normally re-launches the app and reloads its components, while hot reloading re-renders the screen instantly without reloading its components. so, live reload actually does help in some ways. also, once you have the app running on android, you can force a reload by tapping `R` twice or bring up a menu for more options using `CTRL + M`. on a physical android device, you should shake the device to bring up that same menu.

Comment: @kenmistry Using the reload option from the menu looks like it works well, I'll use that more then. I tried changing to a different version of RNRF and I haven't been able to launch my app since, getting the error 'Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug'. I think I have to go back to my backup and start over again or something. I feel like I'm digging myself deeper and deeper trying to get this current project running.

Comment: glad that it helps. i see. what i can recommend is that you revert the `react-native` version to the one used in your backup. upgrading `react-native` from 0.56.x to 0.57.x can have a big impact on your app as all other packages will need to be upgraded and checked for compatibility. upgrading `react-native` from 0.56.0 to 0.56.x, on the other hand, may not impact your app greatly. as for the `installDebug` error, have you tried using `yarn android` or running the app on Android Studio?

Comment: @kenmistry yarn android just says the following to me: yarn run v1.12.3
error Command "android" not found.

As for android studio I was not able to get it running in the first place there. It first had no module after importing using the existing gradle settings so I couldn't run it to check. Then after I read I should import and let it re-create the structure from scratch I did that but now I have 3 modules and none work because they lack a default activity and if I look at the src files in android studio there's none of the project files remaining, just R files, buildconfigs and manifests